# Can you do HtmlDecode & HtmlEncode in Silverlight?

Tags: string, silverlight, httpcontext, html-encode

So since `System.Web` & `HttpContext` isn't available in Silverlight is there a way to do `HtmlDecode` & `HtmlEncode` inside a Silverlight app without some horrendous Regex?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[System.Windows.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser(VS.95).aspx) has an [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.httputility(VS.95).aspx) class with [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.httputility.htmlencode(VS.95).aspx) and [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.httputility.htmldecode(VS.95).aspx) methods.

Comment: This method only replaces the characters <, >, & and ". Is there a better way to also replace line feeds and other speical characters?

Comment: @helb what would you replace a line feed with? HtmlEncoding is to ensure that a text blob can be safely passed through an HTML parser without triggering any DOM parsing... need to understand better what your actual need is. I suggest opening a new question.